# Drawing background image into form overflow client area

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I have a problem with drawing image on form background. I have a form where there are inserted both scrollbars (H and V). Because I need to be able display image in original size I use them for scrolling it but when I scroll to maximum right or bottom on both sides missing 7 pixels which are hidden under scrollbars. There is sample code:

```
private int PosX, PosY;
this.Map = new Bitmap(TestLines.Properties.Resources.mapa);

protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaintBackground(e);
    if (this.Map != null)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(Map, new Point(this.PosX, this.PosY));

        int MapResX = (int)((float)this.Map.Width / this.Map.HorizontalResolution * e.Graphics.DpiX);
        int MapResY = (int)((float)this.Map.Height / this.Map.VerticalResolution * e.Graphics.DpiY);

        if (MapResX > this.ClientSize.Width && MapResY > this.ClientSize.Height - this.toolStrip1.Height)
        {
            hScrollBar1.Minimum = 0;
            hScrollBar1.Maximum = MapResX - this.ClientSize.Width + vScrollBar1.Width;
            hScrollBar1.Visible = true;
            vScrollBar1.Minimum = 0;
            vScrollBar1.Maximum = MapResY - this.ClientSize.Height + toolStrip1.Height + hScrollBar1.Height;
            vScrollBar1.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (MapResX > this.ClientSize.Width)
        {
            hScrollBar1.Minimum = 0;
            hScrollBar1.Maximum = MapResX - this.ClientSize.Width;
            hScrollBar1.Visible = true;
            vScrollBar1.Visible = false;
        }
        else if (MapResY > this.ClientSize.Height - this.toolStrip1.Height)
        {
            vScrollBar1.Minimum = 0;
            vScrollBar1.Maximum = MapResY - this.ClientSize.Height + toolStrip1.Height;
            vScrollBar1.Visible = true;
            hScrollBar1.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            hScrollBar1.Visible = false;
            vScrollBar1.Visible = false;
        }
    }            
}
```

Note that there is also a toolstrip where i do not draw. And then simple scrollbars actions:

```
private void hScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    this.PosX = -e.NewValue;
    this.Invalidate(false);
    this.Update();
}

private void vScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    this.PosY = toolStrip1.Height -e.NewValue;
    this.Invalidate(false);
    this.Update();
}
```

Can you describe me why this happens ?

Answer (score 1):

This is just not the right way to go about it.  Create your own control instead, using Panel as the base class so you get the scrolling for free.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop it from the top of the toolbox onto your form, you probably want to set its Dock property to Fill.  Assign the Map property, either with the designer or in your code.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MapPanel : Panel {
    public MapPanel() {
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        this.ResizeRedraw = true;
    }

    private Image map;
    public Image Map {
        get { return map; }
        set {
            map = value;
            this.AutoScrollMinSize = value == null ? Size.Empty : value.Size;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e) {
        base.OnPaintBackground(e);
        if (map != null) {
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(this.AutoScrollPosition.X, this.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(map, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I had it done by panel before and its good solution but I decide to do it on form itself. So I just ask why these pixels missing on the right and bottom side when I scroll full right or full left respectively.